# In skimage, How to transform an image array to binary type？

Tags: tensorflow, python-imaging-library, scikit-image, tfrecord

I'm doing some deep learning CNN work using tensorflow, I wanna load image dataset and change its type to TFRecord as recommended. When I use PIL library, it work fine:

```
for img_name in os.listdir(class_path):
        img_path = class_path + img_name  

        img = Image.open(img_path)
        img = img.resize((250,250))
        img_raw = img.tobytes()  ### change ndarray to bytes 
        example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
            "label": tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[index])),
            'img_raw': tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[img_raw]))
        }))  
        writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
```

Take notice of the # line，it's nessesary to do so and pass it to tf.train.Example method. Now I wanna using skimage library to do the same operation, but I cannot find the exactly API to do so, only find skimage.utl.image_as_ubytes, but it transform the image to 8-bit int style. So, I'm confused, how can I transform the image data to binary mode using skimage? In the follow it's my snnipets using skimage and it failed

```
 for i in np.arange(0, imageNum):
    image = io.imread(imageList[i])
    image = transform.resize(image, (32,32,3), 0)
     # - 0: Nearest-neighbor
     # - 1: Bi-linear (default)
     # - 2: Bi-quadratic
     # - 3: Bi-cubic
     # - 4: Bi-quartic
     # - 5: Bi-quintic
    image = util.img_as_ubyte(image)#unit8

    label = int(labels[i])
    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'label': tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[label])),
        'image_raw': bytes_feature(image)}))
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
```

Comment: Make the image binary first, then change to a byte array?

Comment: Does `img_as_bool` help?